# Data Grid not allowing any other control

Tags: c#, wpf

I cant see any my stack panel on UI ,Data Grid take all the available UI space.Why?

```
  <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red"  >
            <TextBox Height="50" Width="250">t1</TextBox>
            <Slider></Slider>
            <TextBox>t2</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
        <DataGrid   Name="DGComm" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding LogMessagesList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time Stamp." Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}'}"  Width="0.1*"/>
              .
              .

        </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: specify <DataGrid Grid.Row="1">.remove <Grid Grid.Row="1" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for not displaying stack
- You have closed Grid tag before putting anything into it.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

I am assuming this from your XAML posted in question.
Try following code

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red"  >
        <TextBox Height="50" Width="250">t1</TextBox>
        <Slider></Slider>
        <TextBox>t2</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
   <Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid   Name="DGComm" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding LogMessagesList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time Stamp." Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}'}"  Width="0.1*"/>  
              </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

     </Grid>
```

Comment: Eventually we learn from our mistakes, this happens to everyone. :)